# Данные на иврите полученные из PHP в кодировке UTF8 не читабельные в C#

Tags: php, c#, mysql, utf-8

Пытаюсь преобразовать данные на иврите  из My Sql c помощью запроса к php  - данные получаю в нормальном виде в броузере - но в C#  не получается получить их в нормальном виде.
Пробовал перекодировку в C# - тоже не помогает.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public const string ListProjectUrl = "https://mysite.co.il/pm/Projects.php?code=1234";
       

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
   
        private static string[] getPhpData(string varExtUrl)
        {
            var res = new WebClient().DownloadString(varExtUrl);
            string[] items = res.Split('\n');
            return items;
        }

        private void lvProjects_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] projectItems = getPhpData(ListProjectUrl);
            List<Project> items = new List<Project>();
            foreach (string prItem in projectItems)
            {

                if (prItem.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] words = prItem.Split(';');
                    string str3 = "ירודגכךלחדגךדלחגיכדג";
                    string str3_4 = Utf8ToUtf16Short(str3);
                    string decodestr1 = Utf16ToUtf8Short(words[3]);                 
                    string decodestr2 = Utf8ToUtf16Short(words[3]);
                    
                    items.Add(item: new Project() { Num = words[0], Name = words[1], Code = words[2], ProjectN = words[3] });
                }
                else
                    break;
            }

            lvProjects.ItemsSource = items;
        }
        static string UTF8ToWin1251(string sourceStr)
        {
            Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
            Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");
            byte[] utf8Bytes = utf8.GetBytes(sourceStr);
            byte[] win1251Bytes = Encoding.Convert(win1251, utf8, utf8Bytes);
            return win1251.GetString(win1251Bytes);
        }

        public static string Utf16ToUtf8Short(string utf16String)
        {
            
            byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(utf16String);
            byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, utf16Bytes);

            return Encoding.Default.GetString(utf8Bytes);
        }
        public static string Utf8ToUtf16Short(string utf8String)
        {
            byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(utf8String);
            byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, utf8Bytes);

            return Encoding.Default.GetString(utf16Bytes);
        }

    }
    
 }
```

Вот пример входных данных :

1. שלום עליכם  46-44;- так вижу в броузере
2. ×©×œ×•× ×¢×œ×™×›× 46-44;-до  перекодирования
3. ?©???•?? ?????™?›??  46-44; - После перекодировки

Цель- получить данные в C# аналогично как в п.1(из броузера)

Comment: Какая кодовая страница указана на странице, с которой вы пытаетесь получить данные?

Comment: Уверен изначальная кодировка Win1251 и конвертируется в UTF8. Попробуйте `Encoding.Convert(win1251, utf8, utf8Bytes);`

Comment: Кодовая страница установлена в источнике PHP  - вот так $result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Comment: Р“вЂ”Р’В©Р“вЂ”Р•вЂњР“вЂ”РІР‚СћР“вЂ”Р’Сњ Р“вЂ”Р’СћР“вЂ”Р•вЂњР“вЂ”РІвЂћСћР“вЂ”РІР‚С”Р“вЂ”Р’Сњ 46-44 - "
Уверен изначальная кодировка Win1251 и конвертируется в UTF8. Попробуйте Encoding.Convert(win1251, utf8, utf8Bytes); – Геннадий П 1 час назад
" - не сработало((

Comment: Похоже , что 1251 - тут вообще не при чем, текст на иврите - но как указать кодовую страницу CP862 - вместо "Windows-1251"?

Comment: `но в C# не получается получить их в нормальном виде` Каким образом в шарпе получаете данные? Вы показали костыль, который пытаетесь воткнуть, но не показали код, который и есть источник проблемы. Не находите это странным?

Comment: Проблема на моменте формирования данных из PHP , непонятно почему в броузере данные отображаются корректно, а те же данные прочитанные из C# читаю уже "кривые" .  Вот образец данных из броузера  
**23;AR11;213;ארלינג'ר 11 תל אביב;Erlinger_11**  
**26;BE17;219;בית אשל 17 תל אביב;Beit_Eshel_17**
------  
Данные из C#  
23;AR11;213;××¨×œ×™× ×’'×¨ 11 ×ª×œ ××‘×™×‘;Erlinger_11  
26;BE17;219;×‘×™×ª ××©×œ 17 ×ª×œ ××‘×™×‘;Beit_Eshel_17

Comment: Чтобы обратиться к собеседнику тегайте его @aepot, тогда собеседник получит уведомление о том, что вы ему написали. Код надо вставить в сам вопрос, а не в комментарии. Вопрос можно редактировать. Покажите код метода `getPhpData()`

Comment: Уберите весь код из комментариев, который вы запостили (удалите комментарии), и отредактируйте вопрос (кнопка Править), внесите код туда. Вам было бы удобно читать такой код в комментариях? Покажите в вопросе все методы из стека вызовов, начиная от обработчика событий, заканчивая `getPhpData`.

Comment: @aepot - код отредатирован, с учетом полного стека вызовов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте попробуем изменить технологию получения данных

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async Task<string[]> GetPhpDataAsync(string varExtUrl)
{
    string res = await client.GetStringAsync(varExtUrl);
    return res.Split('\n');
}

private async void lvProjects_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string[] projectItems = await GetPhpDataAsync(ListProjectUrl);

        // ваш код
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

`HttpClient` должен определить кодировку скачиваемых данных автоматически по заголовку `Content-Type: ...;charset=...`

При этом вам вообще не нужно производить какие-либо дополнительные преобразования.

Если `async/await` - не  понятно, что такое, почитайте это: [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: Спасибо большое .

Также изменил метод чтения данных на HttpClient - и все заработало, как и должно!!!
Пример кода:    
private static string[] getPhpData(string varExtUrl)
        {
            var res = new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(varExtUrl).Result;
            //var res = new WebClient().DownloadString(varExtUrl);
            string[] items = res.Split('\n');

            return items;
        }

К сожалению-не получилось отформатировать в ответе данные((

Comment: @ВячеславЛан `GetStringAsync(varExtUrl).Result` - не используйте `Task.Result` никогда для незавершенных тасков, это может привести к полному зависанию приложения (deadlock). Используйте `await`. Вторая ошибка - `new HttpClient()`, не следует создавать новый `HttpClient` на каждый запрос, это может привести к истощению набора свободных сокетов и вы просто потеряете связь с сетью. Нужно создать один экземпляр и переиспользовать его, как показано в ответе выше, а так же в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1#examples).

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, передела код согласно вашему, работает отлично. Прошу прощения за паузу